# Remove numbered chapter titles that do not have text immediately below

Tags: regex, shell, sed, grep

I have text files that list of 3000 to 5000 lines that I'll call numbered chapter titles.  I want to delete the rows that do not have text (sentances) immediately below the title.

Like:

```
Chapter 1
Chapter 2
Chapter 3
Hello world
Chapter 4
Chapter 5
I love you. 
Chapter 6
how many times do I have to do this
chapter 7
Chapter 8
Chapter 9
Some lines have some numbers, numbers and text.
some chapter text has multiple lines.
I thought the best method is to
look for a chapter header line 
that has a chapter header line 
immediately below it.  The last chapter 
line becomes an issue if it does 
not have any text.
Chapter 10
```

I want to remove the lines Chapter 1, 2, 4, 7, 8 and 10

I tried to match with grep and sed with a Chapter line if the following line was also a Chapter line using positive lookaheads (the lookahead would not be deleted)

`grep -Pz '(?s)Chapter\s[\d]{4}\n(?=(Chapter\s[\d]{4}\n)) filename.txt`

or in sed (I'm not understanding the scripts with sed)...

`sed 's/(?s)Chapter\s[\d]{4}\n(?=(Chapter\s[\d]{4}\n))/ /g' filename.txt`

Grep doesn't do multi-line well (everything becomes one line if you use the -Pz tags. If everything is one line, then anything that matches anywhere means the line is a match.

I also tried using sed, with a look aheads  so, I cannot use look-ahead since part of the one line matched.

I know I can do this with python or other scripting language but it is much too slow vs. the bash commands.  I was able to process to this level from a bigger mess very quickly vs python so I was hoping I could get to this last step with bash commands only and keep our update window much shorter.  The files are huge and there is much more random text in the chapters that have text.  It can be multiple sentednces.

Cheers and thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one which awk/gawk does quite well - and for awk this one is fast.

Algorithm - You either remember the previous line, OR, dump the previous line and current, or just the current (depending on what happened previously).  It's quite wordy, but very quick to write.

```
awk '
BEGIN { last=""; }
/^[Cc]hapter *[0-9][0-9]* *$/ {
  last=$0;
  next;
}
/.*/ {
  if (last) {
    print last;
    last="";
  }
  print $0;
  next;
}' IP.txt
```

Normally you also want an END block - but in this case if last is set it is irrelevant.

Comment: also works flawlessly. Thank you!  I'm just having trouble getting my arms around how the script works.
Here is the desired result (with the last Chapter header removed)

Chapter 3
Hello world
Chapter 5
I love you. 
Chapter 6
how many times do I have to do this
Chapter 9
Some lines have some numbers, numbers and text.
some chapter text has multiple lines.
I thought the best method is to
look for a chapter header line 
that has a chapter header line 
immediately below it.  The last chapter 
line becomes an issue if it does 
not have any text.

Comment: You have two types of lines that are processed - Chapters headings or ANYTHING else. We use the last variable to build a simple state machine ... If last is defined you had a chapter heading on the previous line - so if you then get another chapter heading - you can just ignore the last one (setting up for the next line by remembering the last heading)...  If you get anything else but have last set - then you have a chapter heading you had to keep - so print it, then print the currently processed line, and we are then back to the starting state.

Answer (score 1):

If `perl` is your option, would you please try:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/Chapter\s*\d+\n(?=Chapter\s*\d+\n)|Chapter\s*\d+\n?$//ig' filename.txt > newfile.txt
```

I have generated a file with ~5,000 lines to test. Then the script above completed within several milliseconds.

Explanations:

- The option `-0777` tells `perl` to slurp all lines at once to process the input across the lines.
- The regex `Chapter\s*\d+\n(?=Chapter\s*\d+\n)|Chapter\s*\d+\n?$` matches a line of chapter which is immediately followed by another chapter line or end of the file.

Comment: I assume I can leave off the -0777 if I push the list in as std input from a grep or cat, correct?

Comment: Nope. The default (w/o -0777) behavor of `perl` is to process the input line by line as `grep`, `sed` or `awk` even if you feed the file into the stdin of `perl` via a pipeline.

Comment: it took a few minutes because I didn't realize there is a \r\n at the end of each paragraph (I assumed just \n (not your fault, of course)).  Thank a bunch. It works except for the last line - if there is no text after the last Chapter header, the last chapter header remains.  I can look into other options.  The main work is done - and it is very fast. good work.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have intended to consider the case the last
line is a chapter header with no text (as `Chapter 10` in your example).
The possible problem is your file does not have the end-of-line code
at the end of the file. Of course it is not your fault but a troublesome
behavior of Windows text editor.
I have fixed my script accordingly. If you are satisfied with the accepted answer, it's
all right. But I'd be happy if you have a time to test my updated script. BR.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -e '
/^[Cc]hapter [0-9]/!b
:Z
$d
N
/\n[Cc]hapter [0-9]/{D;bZ;}
' -- data
```

On match opens a 2-line window appending (`N`) next line to current.
If two consecutive matches deletes (`D`) the first and resumes. A
match on last line gets deleted (`$d`).